# Летнее время Java Hibernate MySQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, java, время, mysql

Работа с временем - ужасная штука.

На локальном компьютере запущен mysql сервер и java приложение. Когда получаю дату из mysql, и вывожу её в java, получается на час меньше. Что делать?

Значение загружается вот в такое поле

```
@Column(name = "updated_time")
private Timestamp updatedTime;
```

Выводится для проверка в java

```
System.out.println(question.getUpdatedTime().getTime());
```

и в mysql

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(updated_time) FROM questions
```

Вот настройки jdbc

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/qa
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=****
```

А вот HibernateConfig (Spring)

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    private @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    String jdbcDriver;
    private @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    String jdbcUrl;
    private @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    String jdbcUsername;
    private @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    String jdbcPassword;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriver);
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(jdbcUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(jdbcPassword);

        return dataSource;
    }

    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        p.put("hibernate.show_sql","false");
        p.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return p;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource());
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("ru.kapahgaiii.qa.domain");
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getHibernateConfig(){
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("jdbc.properties"));
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Вы java патчили на предмет исправления часовых поясов? Если сделать просто `System.out.println(new Date());`, то время правильно выводится?

Comment: Не понятно, за что мне минус.   
@Slava Semushin, нет, не патчил. Кто же знал, что её патчить надо? Да, выводится неправильно, на час больше. Если хотите, оформите комментарий как ответ.

Comment: @Slava Semushin, блин, пропатчил, теперь из консоли нормально работает, а в intellij idea нифига. Не знаете, что делать?

Comment: Найдите, какую Java использует IDEA, и пропатчите ее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основании вашего вопроса и комментария ясно, что вам необходимо пропатчить вашу Java, чтобы применить последние изменения в часовых зонах.

1) Если у вас установлена OpenJDK из пакета (RPM/dpkg)

Обновите пакет `tzdata-java`

2) Если у вас установлен JDK "ручным способом" (например, вы распаковали тарболл в `/opt`)

[Скачайте утилиту `tzupdater` с сайта Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html) и скопируйте на сервер (например, в каталог `/opt`). Далее выполните:

```
cd /opt
unzip tzupdater-1_4_8-2014h.zip
rm -fv tzupdater-1_4_8-2014h.zip 
cd /opt/jdk1.8.0_11
java -jar /opt/tzupdater-1.4.8-2014h/tzupdater.jar -u
```

Если у вас установлено несколько версий java в различных каталогах, то необходимо выполнить подобные действия для каждой из них.

Также, вероятно, понадобится перезапустить текущие java процессы.

Ссылки по теме:

- http://habrahabr.ru/post/241411/
- http://habrahabr.ru/post/131573/

Comment: @Slava Semushin, утилиту я уже скачал и проапдейтил. Из консоли теперь работает номально. А вот Intellij IDEA всё равно неверно показывает. Пробовал задавать параметр -Duser.timezone виртуальной машине. Результаты такие
-Duser.timezone="Europe/Kiev" - на час меньше, чем у меня  
-Duser.timezone="Europe/Moscow" - на час больше, чем у меня (я в московском поясе)    
-Duser.timezone="Etc/GMT-3" - идеально.  
На том и успокоился, просто буду задавать нужный парметр и всё.